# Android invoke method in intentservice running in background

Tags: android, service

I am new to android. I have a intentservice running in Background that logs acceleration, barometer sensor data.

I would like to add a button on the activity to unregister barometer sensor on the service. I had a private method in service that unregister the sensor. I was thinking to send a broadcast to the service when the button is clicked.

Is there a better way to do this?